# How to generate variable number of Outputs in Plotly Dash

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am working on a Dash application for performance monitoring using python and plotly.

I have 18 dbc **tabs** .
In each tab i have a **tab_content**. Each **tab_content** has :

- a dbc.Card with  dbc columns (graphs embedded in the columns).
- an image button for toggling between showing the graphs in a grid and  showing them one on top of each other.

[image]
Each time the user presses the toggle button i want to trigger  a callback that changes the following properites:

- **the 'xl' property** of the dbc.columns for the viewed tab. The number of columns differ per tab depending on the number of charts .  For example, first tab "CSSR Voce" has a button 'btn-1', and 2 dbc.columns with id's : 'g11', 'g12' (each column has a dcc.Graph embedded in it )
- **the image of the  button** . I have 2 images : 1 and 2. First time, the button loads with image 1. When user presses it switches to image 2.
- **the width of the dbc.Card** embeding the dbc.Columns When showing graphs on top of each other i change the width to 1000. When showing the graps one NEXT to each other i change the width to 2000.

**My approach was like this**:
Because i have 18 toggler buttons i declared:

- 18 id's with {index:''} for the image and 18 id's for the buttons identifiers and wrote one single callback for all the 18 tabs using MATCH.

**The problem:**: I can use MATCH to reference the buttons, images and card styles because these  have only one index per callback  but when it comes to updating the 'xl' column i cannot use MATCH because each tab has more than one graph. So , would not know how to do a one-2-one index match in my callback.

When I write the  callback I would need  a variable number of outputs for updating the "xl" of each tab's dbc columns  for each tab. I tried using a comprehension but cannot  pass the variable 'nbr' outside the decorated function and into the decorator's arguments ( expected that not to work but tried it annyway)

**The callback i wrote:**

```
@app.callback(
    [Output(f"{g}", 'xl') for g in tabs_graphs[nbr] +
    [Output({'name':'card','index':MATCH}, 'style'), Output({'name':'img','index':MATCH}, 'src')],

    Input({'name':'btn','index':MATCH}, 'n_clicks')
)
def grid(n_clicks):
    tabs_graphs = [

        ['g11', 'g12'],
        ['g21', 'g22'],
        ['g31'],
        ['g41', 'g42', 'g43'],
        ['g51', 'g52'],
        ['g61', 'g62', 'g63'],
        ['g71', 'g72', 'g73'],
        ['g81', 'g82', 'g83', 'g84'],
        ['g91', 'g92', 'g93'],
        ['g101', 'g102', 'g103'],
        ['g111', 'g112', 'g113', 'g114'],
        ['g121', 'g122', 'g123'],
        ['g131', 'g132'],
        ['g141']

    ]


    if (n_clicks % 2) != 0:
        xl = 12
        style = {'width': 1000}
        src = './assets/grid2.png'
        index_dict_string=str(dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0])

        if index_dict_string != '':
            nbr = int(json.loads(index_dict_string)['index'])
            print('nbr is:', nbr)
            return [xl for g in tabs_graphs[nbr+1]]+[style, src]

        else:
            raise PreventUpdate

    else:
        xl = 6

        style = {'width': 2000}
        src = './assets/grid1.png'
        index_dict_string = str(dash.callback_context.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0])

        if index_dict_string !='':
            nbr=int(json.loads(index_dict_string)['index'])
            print('nbr is:',nbr)

            return [xl for g in tabs_graphs[nbr+1]]+[style, src]
            
        else:
            raise PreventUpdate
```

**the HTML structure of the tabs:**

```
tab1_content = dbc.Card(
                            dbc.CardBody(
                                [
                                    dbc.Row([

                                            html.Div([
                                                html.Button(
                                                    html.Img(src='./assets/grid1.png',className='icon',id={'name':'img','index':1}),
                                                    className='grdbutton1',
                                                    n_clicks=0,
                                                    id={'name':'btn','index':1},
                                                    )

                                            ],id='btn-grid',style={'width':'100%'})
                                        ],
                                    ),

                                    dbc.Row(
                                        [
                                            dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='CSSR_voce_1'),id='g11', sm=12,md=12,lg=12,xl=6),
                                            dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='CSSR_voce_2'),id='g12',sm=12,md=12,lg=12,xl=6),
                                        ],
                                        no_gutters=True,
                                    )
                                ],

                            ),
                            id={'name':'card','index':1},
                            className="mt-3",
                            style={'width':2000}
                        ),
```

Comment: I think you'd have to use `ALL` instead of `MATCH` for this.

Comment: it looks like it ..yes. I can't think of another solution